# onclick="$('#id').toggle()" didn't work, need to rewrite for Chrome older versions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, onclick, toggle

I need help with the next issue. In my code, to toggle some fields I'm using

```
 <a onclick="$('#toggledFormId').toggle()" >Presss</a>
```

and for me everything was fine, but get issue during the test on other computers. Nothing happends, no errors, no alerts, no toggling.

I know that it's because my version of Chrome is the last one, and on the test computers older, but I need to find universal solution.

I tried this

```
<script> 
   $('#hrefId').click(function()
   {
      $('#toggledFormId').toggle();
   });
</script>
```

this

```
<script>
   $('#hrefId').on('click', function(){
     $('#toggledFormId').toggle();
   });
</script>
```

both of this variant by using classes(not id) and some other similar, not to comlicated variants, but with no results.

I will be grateful for any suggestion, especially if it works ^_^

Comment: why not just update the chrome version to the latest?

Comment: Did you try to wrap your bind event inside document ready?

Comment: @Monkey_Dev1400 app in use and this for new feature, need to update Chrome for more then 200 computers

Comment: @TanDuong  I'd like to avoid this, but according to your question it will be the best solution?

Comment: Or you can try with `$(document).on('click', '#hrefId', function(event){})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny, but non of methods that were purposed didn't work untill...

AdBlock and other similar programs do not let the fields open up. Maybe they think that toggle part of the form is spam or something like this, so after they were disabling suggested solutions started work.

Thank you everyone for help.

Answer (score 1):

There might be various reasons why it won't work on older chrome versions.

1. You simply made a spelling mistake with your ids => check your spelling and avoid duplicate ids
2. One or more closing tags in your markup are missing(if so, chrome attempts to 
   close them and often miserably fails.).
       => check your markup and try again.
3. Your items are being added dynamically. In this case try:

```html
$( "body" ).on( "click", "#hrefId", function() {
  $('#toggledFormId').toggle();
});
```